# How to redirect a page from a View to a Controller in ASP.NET MVC 3?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm using mvc3 with Razor Engine and I have a condition that when it's true should redirect automaticaly to another page sending an object as parameter. What I want to do is:

> @if (cond > 10)
>   {
>
> > Url.Action("Edit", product); //redirect in this line automaticaly to the action Edit sending the object as parameter
> >     }

Somebody knows if exist a Html.Helper that do this for me?
I mean redirect to a page like this: someHtmlHelper("myAction", "myController", myObject).

I tried do this using JavaScript and almost works, I just find some problems in url parameter. The Url.Action returns the symbol code instead the caracter for the special caracters. Like "&" instead "&".

> @if (cond > 10)
>   {
>   var url = Url.Action("Edit", product);
>
> > var Url = '@url';
> >     location.href = Url;
> >
> > <}

The url result is:
http://localhost:4772/Product/Edit?ProductId=2234&Code=0020582&Name...

I will be injured if MVC3 doesn't has a single page redirect implemented.

So I need help.
Thanks.

Comment: @Renvn Is the property `cond` coming from a controller? If so, why not do the redirect from there while the request is still server-side?

Answer (score 3):

The view isn't the appropriate place for that sort of logic.

Depending on your solution you should either:

A)  Check the condition in yor Controller, prior to returning the View, and redirect there like so:

```
if (cond >= 10) 
    return RedirectToAction("ADifferentResult");
```

B)  Use partial views to conditionally RenderAction like:

```
@{
    if (cond > 10) 
        Html.RenderAction("ADifferentResult");
    else
        Html.RenderAction("DefaultResult");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@if (cond > 10){@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Product", new { ProductId = 2234, Code = 0020582 })}
```